# mdadm array won't assemble on boot, assembles manually with device list

Tags: boot, raid, mdadm

I'm running 14.04 LTS with a 5 drive Software RAID array with 2TB drives.  mdadm, lvm and xfs.  My primary boot device is a 256GB SSD.

Had a power outage, and when the power came back, the system wouldn't boot.  When trying to boot, the following is scrolled on the screen repeatedly so I couldn't get past the boot process:

```
    Incrementally starting RAID arrays... 
    mdadm: CREATE user root not found 
    mdadm: CREATE group disk not found
    Incrementally started RAID arrays.
```

There is a bug on launchpad for this (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mdadm/+bug/1335642), but there doesn't seem to be a definitive workaround - or at least steps easily repeatable by me.

Booting into recovery mode, lists the following information:

```
[ 2.482387] md: bind<sdb1> 
[ 2.408390] md: bind<sda1> 
[ 2.438005] md: bind<sdc1> 
[ 2.986691] Switched to clocksource tsc 
Incrementally starting RAID arrays... 
mdadm: CREATE user root not found 
mdadm: CREATE group disk not found 
[ 31.755948] md/raid:md0: device sdc1 operational as raid disk 1 
[ 31.756886] md/raid:md0: device sda1 operational as raid disk 0 
[ 31.756861] md/raid:md0: device sdb1 operational as raid disk 2 
[ 31.756115] md/raid:md0: device sdd1 operational as raid disk 3 
[ 31.756531] md/raid:md0: allocated 0kB 
[ 31.756647] md/raid:md0: raid level 5 active with 4 out of 5 devices, algorithm 2 
[ 31.756735] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 8001591181312
mdadm: started array /dev/md0
Incrementally started RAID arrays. 
[ 31.757933] random: nonblocking pool is initialized 
[ 31.758184]  md0: unknown partition table 
[ 31.781641] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
Incrementally starting RAID arrays... 
mdadm: CREATE user root not found 
mdadm: CREATE group disk not found 
Incrementally started RAID arrays.
```

So, booting into a Live CD, the drives all look ok via SMART data.  If I try to run `mdadm --assemble --scan` I get the following warning:

```
mdadm: WARNING /dev/sde1 and /dev/sde appear to have very similar superblocks.
      If they are really different, please --zero the superblock on one
      If they are the same or overlap, please remove one from the
      DEVICE list in mdadm.conf.
```

The array is not assembled.

I captured all of the RAID device info here:

```
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : d5f6a94e:185828ec:b1902148:b8793263
  Creation Time : Tue Feb 15 18:47:10 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1953513472 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 7814053888 (7452.06 GiB 8001.59 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Tue Aug  2 11:43:38 2016
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 1af33e59 - correct
         Events : 105212

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1     1       8       65        1      active sync   /dev/sde1
   2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   3     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   4     4       8        1        4      active sync   /dev/sda1
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : d5f6a94e:185828ec:b1902148:b8793263
  Creation Time : Tue Feb 15 18:47:10 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1953513472 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 7814053888 (7452.06 GiB 8001.59 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Tue Aug  2 11:43:38 2016
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 1af33e6d - correct
         Events : 105212

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1     1       8       65        1      active sync   /dev/sde1
   2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   3     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   4     4       8        1        4      active sync   /dev/sda1
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : d5f6a94e:185828ec:b1902148:b8793263
  Creation Time : Tue Feb 15 18:47:10 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1953513472 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 7814053888 (7452.06 GiB 8001.59 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Tue Aug  2 11:43:38 2016
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 1af33e7b - correct
         Events : 105212

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8       65        1      active sync   /dev/sde1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1     1       8       65        1      active sync   /dev/sde1
   2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   3     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   4     4       8        1        4      active sync   /dev/sda1
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : d5f6a94e:185828ec:b1902148:b8793263
  Creation Time : Tue Feb 15 18:47:10 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1953513472 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 7814053888 (7452.06 GiB 8001.59 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Tue Aug  2 11:43:38 2016
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 1af33e8f - correct
         Events : 105212

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1     1       8       65        1      active sync   /dev/sde1
   2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   3     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   4     4       8        1        4      active sync   /dev/sda1
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : d5f6a94e:185828ec:b1902148:b8793263
  Creation Time : Tue Feb 15 18:47:10 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1953513472 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 7814053888 (7452.06 GiB 8001.59 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Tue Aug  2 11:43:38 2016
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 1af33e41 - correct
         Events : 105212

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     4       8        1        4      active sync   /dev/sda1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1     1       8       65        1      active sync   /dev/sde1
   2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   3     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   4     4       8        1        4      active sync   /dev/sda1
```

Original /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf (nothing crazy):

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=0.90 UUID=d5f6a94e:185828ec:b1902148:b8793263

# This file was auto-generated on Wed, 09 May 2012 23:34:51 -0400
# by mkconf $Id$
```

So, if I run `sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1` (depending on which drives are the raid drives) then the array assembles correctly and I can access the files.

I have tried to pull the power from all of the RAID drives, the system still doesn't boot (same infinite loop).

I have tried to `chroot` and define each device in the array in /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf and then update initramfs, which is where I am now, and the system still won't boot.

Here is the new `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers
DEVICE /dev/sd[abcde]1

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
#ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=0.90 UUID=d5f6a94e:185828ec:b1902148:b8793263
ARRAY /dev/md0 devices=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1,/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdd1,/dev/sde1

# This file was auto-generated on Wed, 09 May 2012 23:34:51 -0400
# by mkconf $Id$
```

What I don't understand is what is causing the system not to assemble on boot, when I can assemble manually by specifying the devices.

One of the remaining things that seem odd is that I recorded the boot process on slow-mo camera, and don't see `/dev/sde` or `/dev/sde1` in the boot messages.  I'm going to look into that, but don't really know what to look into.

**Update - Sat Aug 13**

I've been doing more investigations.  So, doing a `sudo fdisk -l` shows the following for the drives in the RAID 5:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xca36f687

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   fd  Linux raid autodetect

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398933504 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029167 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  3907029166  1953514583   ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf66042a2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sde: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2006adb2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdf: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0008b3d6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdg: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd46f102b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdg1              64  3907029167  1953514552   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

So, obviously here `/dev/sdg1` starts at a different sector location than the other RAID partitions.  So, next step was to examine the `/dev/sdg` drive.  As you can see by the following 4 commands, mdadm doesn't examine `/dev/sdg` drive and detect the RAID like it does for the other drives (`/dev/sda` used as an example below).  ***Is this a hint as to what is actually wrong?***

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdg
/dev/sdg:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907029104 sectors at           64 (type fd)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdg1
/dev/sdg1:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 0.90.00
       UUID : d5f6a94e:185828ec:b1902148:b8793263
  Creation Time : Tue Feb 15 18:47:10 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1953513472 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 7814053888 (7452.06 GiB 8001.59 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sun Aug 14 03:04:59 2016
      State : clean
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 1b029700 - correct
     Events : 105212

     Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1     1       8       65        1      active sync   /dev/sde1
   2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   3     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   4     4       8        1        4      active sync   /dev/sda1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 0.90.00
       UUID : d5f6a94e:185828ec:b1902148:b8793263
  Creation Time : Tue Feb 15 18:47:10 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1953513472 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 7814053888 (7452.06 GiB 8001.59 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sun Aug 14 03:04:59 2016
      State : clean
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 1b0296b2 - correct
     Events : 105212

     Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     4       8        1        4      active sync   /dev/sda1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1     1       8       65        1      active sync   /dev/sde1
   2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   3     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   4     4       8        1        4      active sync   /dev/sda1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 0.90.00
       UUID : d5f6a94e:185828ec:b1902148:b8793263
  Creation Time : Tue Feb 15 18:47:10 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1953513472 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 7814053888 (7452.06 GiB 8001.59 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sun Aug 14 03:04:59 2016
      State : clean
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 1b0296b2 - correct
     Events : 105212

     Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     4       8        1        4      active sync   /dev/sda1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1     1       8       65        1      active sync   /dev/sde1
   2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   3     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   4     4       8        1        4      active sync   /dev/sda1
```

Lastly, I'm confused by running `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan -v` (verbose mode) because it seems to give a warning about the drive (`/dev/sdf`) and the first (and only) partition (`/dev/sdf1`) looking the same and then stop assembling. See here:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan -v
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdh1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdh
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb5
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb2
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdg
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sr0: No medium found
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop0
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram15
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram14
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram13
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram12
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram11
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram10
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram9
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram8
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram7
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram6
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram5
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram4
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram3
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/ram0
mdadm: /dev/sdg1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 3.
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdf is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: WARNING /dev/sdf1 and /dev/sdf appear to have very similar superblocks.
      If they are really different, please --zero the superblock on one
      If they are the same or overlap, please remove one from the
      DEVICE list in mdadm.conf.
```

At this point, I'm wondering what I should do next?

1. Should I remove /dev/sdg1 from the array, reconstruct it to start at
   sector 2048 and add it back in and let the array reconstruct itself?  If so, what steps should I take?
2. Is there anything actually wrong with starting at sector 64?  Once I
   am able to assemble the array from the LIVE CD by specifying the
   devices to use, is there a way to determine if the '/dev/sdg' drive
   is working properly in the array?  If so, is it worthwhile doing #1
   above, or is there a way to manually set the devices in the array by
   device identifier, etc.?  Specifying the devices in the mdadm.conf
   did not work.
3. Are there other diagnostic steps I should try?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Update - Sept 23, 2016**

So, I tried option #1 above on the drive that started at sector 64.  I failed the drive, removed it from the array and repartitioned the space.  I then added it back in and let it rebuild.  I also ran an offline SMART test on the drive.  All passed and the drive was added back into the array without issue.

I don't know what prompted this next step, but I tried selecting a different kernel revision from the grub menu.  Through the advanced boot options, I CANNOT boot from `3.13.0-92-generic` nor can I boot from `3.13.0-86-generic`.  They both go into the infinite loop.

HOWEVER, I can boot off of `3.13.0-63-generic` and it seems like every other kernel older than that (although I have not tested them all).  Obviously, the system is not working 100%: although it takes me to the GUI, I can't login.  I have to switch to a terminal and login that way.  However, the array is mounted and ready to go and Samba is running fine.

So, my next thought was to look into what was different between the `initrd` images.  I expanded the non-working image and the working image and compared all of the non-binary files and although I'm a rookie, I didn't see anything wrong.

**At this point it seems to be pointing me at a difference between the kernel images, but I'm way out of my depth here and not sure what I should do next.**

**Please help?**